# jQuery post data return comparison not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of code:

```
function addEmail() {
            email = $("#email").val();
            atime = $("select#time").val();
            tid = <?= $tid; ?>;
            $.post("remindme.php", { email: email, time: atime, tid: tid },
                function(data) {
                    if (data == "x") {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#remindme').modal('hide');
                        $('#quota').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#remindme').modal('hide');
                        $('#remindersuccess').show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

`remindme.php` echo's "x" if something is wrong.

I'm trying to compare the output from remindme.php but even though it echo's the x, the condition `data == "x"` does not work.

I added `alert(data)` and I can see it properly displaying the `x` when needed..

Comment: try `alert('"'+x+'"')`. Any whitespaces?

Comment: @ori nope, no white spaces. return "x"

Comment: What's the output of `alert(typeof data);`?

Comment: Then `if (data == 'x')` should work. What's the output of `alert(data == 'x');`? I suspect there's some other problem.

Comment: @hoverhand, I have posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server echoes the `x` string then the `if (data == 'x')` test inside the success callback should work. Your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

maybe is late. I faced same problem and I solved by very stupid workaround (applied to your code):

```
function(data) {
    var server_info = data;
    if (server_info == "x") {                       
         $('#remindme').modal('hide');
          $('#quota').show();
    } else {
         $('#remindme').modal('hide');
         $('#remindersuccess').show();
    }
}
```

I have no idea why :/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem perhaps, and I fixed it like this:

```
    var verify = function (user,fName,fPass) {
        var result = "";
        $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
        $.post("php_scripts/verify"+user+".php",{login:fName, pass:fPass},function (data) {
            result = $.trim(data);   // use $.trim when are you using "data"
        });
        return result;
    }
```